# Top users who are teenagers or underage

Tags: discussion, age, user-information

I am 21 years old. I have always been fascinated when I see teens or young users on Stack Overflow, who are younger than me but in reputations wise, ah!!! I can't compare with mine. They are at that much heights.

And, I have been telling my friends about such users.

In most of the cases, such users' reputation will be more than 10 times of mine.

And the more fascinating fact, is that a subset of such users gained that reputation in less time on SO (i.e they will have been a member for just one year or less).

Ok. I could mention [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) as one such user (also a moderator).

Now, if I sort users based on reputation/memberfor(indays) , and then by ascending order of age, I think I could get my heroes in the front page.

But sadly, there is no such option on SO.

So, could you pick some top 10 such users so that I could at least read their blogs, visit their websites, follow them on Twitter, Facebook and at last share them to my friends.

It would also useful for me, if I get some hints on how to learn concepts that much quickly as them.

Whether it is inborn skill, or it needs a specific method of learning?

Comment: what ? is that matter ?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I was not aware such facility is availabe in SO. Really Thanks for the link. I think my data mining at SO will start from today(in my free times) :-).

Comment: I'd like to clarify that downvotes on meta are different than on the main site, if you haven't realized already. This is a good question overall, but I would assume that the downvotes here mean that people don't think age is a relevant factor to reputation, and thus your question was voted down for that. It [happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174194) [to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178256) [all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140444) of us.

Comment: I'm curious: How will you know when a user is a teenager? Are your choices limited to the teenage users who write their age in their profile?

Comment: FYI: [/legal/terms-of-service/public#age](/legal/terms-of-service/public#age)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually very easy with a simple Data.SE query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110601

```
SELECT TOP 50 
  Id as [User Link],
  Reputation,
  Age
FROM Users
WHERE Age < 20
ORDER BY Reputation DESC
```

Obviously it doesn't have a lower limit, because if you have <s>significant</s> any rep at age 12, you're epic!

Comment: FYI, you must be 13 years old to register on the site...

Comment: @Servy: violating the TOS is "epic".

Comment: @Servy sure, and all of us are over 18 on some websites...

Comment: I'm 19, got almost 80k rep and do not show in that query. Weird.

Comment: Well, I'd think that the site would notice if the birthday you put in would put you as well than 13, so if you are in fact younger, then you still wouldn't show up in the query.

Comment: @RobW Have you put your birthday on your profile?

Comment: I'm 16 and have 3k. I guess I'm awesome.

Comment: @RobW: Are you [having a birthday this year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122742/160410)? (I’m 15, not 16, too.)

Comment: @minitech I'll be twenty by the end of this year.

Comment: I'm 12... I know its a violation kind of but I have 1,237 rep :D